# Selenium: No such element

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Consider [this page](http://suvian.in/selenium/1.10option2.html). I am interested to get the **Congratulations** text using selenium webdriver. Here is the tried code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/font/strong/em/text()")).getText().contains(message);
```

but it complains with:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/font/strong/em/text"}
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7600 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 130 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'salman-PC', ip: '192.168.1.5', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41), userDataDir=C:\Users\salman\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7612_3059}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=59.0.3071.115, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 9ffe01502a1cd688cd022bf5e7719e42
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=/html/body/font/strong/em/text}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at ee.ignite.pages.SelectFromDropDownPage.getText(SelectFromDropDownPage.java:33)
    at ee.ignite.steps.SelectFromDropDown_Steps.i_can_see_the_maessage(SelectFromDropDown_Steps.java:32)
    at ✽.Then I can see the maessage "Congratulations"(D:/Workspace/IgniteTask/src/features/SelectFromDropDown.feature:9)
```

it seems that the path

```
/html/body/font/strong/em/text()
```

is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findElement()` method returns `WebElement`. The `xpath` `"/html/body/font/strong/em/text()"` returns `String`. I'm guessing you received `InvalidSelectorException` so you tried the `xpath` `"/html/body/font/strong/em/text"`, according to the stacktrace, which doesn't exists so you got `NoSuchElementException`.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/font/strong/em")).getText();
```

Should give you the text.

> Edit

To give the `driver` some time to locate the element to prevent timing issues you can set [implicit wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits)

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/font/strong/em")).getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

- Depend on the browser and the performance of your connection the time amount that takes to load the page content will become different.
  So, give some time to load them.
  In here, if you are using JS with your web page, I'm recommending you to use explicit wait.
  Through that, we can define a time amount for web driver to wait until certain requirements to be met before executing the next line of code.

In your case:-

```
  WebDriver webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
  webdriver .get("Your URL");
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver,30);
  WebElement element = wait.untill(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your X-path")));
```

- according to this example code, your web driver will wait 30 seconds of time until the visible of named object.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the text, you need to first store it in some variable which you can print or use as per your need. Below is the sample code.

```
String t1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/font/strong/em")).getText();
System.out.println(t1);
```

I checked it on my machine and it is working fine.